# Neovim: problems with Telescope's history path

Tags: neovim, telescope

when i open telescope every action returns the following:

> E5108: Error executing lua:
> ...sers/josqu/.vim/bundle/plenary.nvim/lua/plenary/path.lua:635: Could
> not create file:
> C:\Users\josqu\C:/Users/josqu/AppData/Local/nvim-data/telescope_history
> stack traceback:  [C]: in function 'error'
> ...sers/josqu/.vim/bundle/plenary.nvim/lua/plenary/path.lua:635: in
> function 'touch'
> .../bundle/telescope.nvim/lua/telescope/actions/history.lua:183: in
> function 'init'
> .../bundle/telescope.nvim/lua/telescope/actions/history.lua:81: in
> function 'handler'
> ...im/bundle/telescope.nvim/lua/telescope/actions/state.lua:50: in
> function 'get_current_history'
> ...squ/.vim/bundle/telescope.nvim/lua/telescope/pickers.lua:1443: in
> function 'on_close_prompt'
> ...vim/bundle/telescope.nvim/lua/telescope/actions/init.lua:386: in
> function 'run_replace_or_original'
> .../.vim/bundle/telescope.nvim/lua/telescope/actions/mt.lua:65: in
> function 'key_func'
> ...qu/.vim/bundle/telescope.nvim/lua/telescope/mappings.lua:257: in
> function
> <...qu/.vim/bundle/telescope.nvim/lua/telescope/mappings.lua:256>

when i run:

```
:lua print(require("plenary.path"):new(vim.fn.expand(vim.fn.stdpath("data") .. "/telescope_history")):absolute())
```

it returns:

```
C:\Users\josqu\C:/Users/josqu/AppData/Local/nvim-data/telescope_history
```

while:

```
:lua print(require("plenary.path"):new(vim.fn.expand(vim.fn.stdpath("data") .. "/telescope_history")):exists())
```

returns false

the telescope checkhealth doesnt flag any problem.

Comment: seems to be related with: https://github.com/nvim-lua/plenary.nvim/pull/324 but the suggested fix (..lua/plenary/path.lua) doesnt fix the problem

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved removing the `set shellslash` setting in my init.vim as suggested here https://github.com/nvim-lua/plenary.nvim/issues/254